# Help about commands of 16x4 LCD - JHD164A

Tags: microcontroller

Can anyone please tell me the commands to display on 2nd, 3rd and, 4th lines of a 16x4 lcd module, JHD164A, i.e; the commands to force the cursor in 2nd, 3rd and 4th lines of LCD. Just like we use 0x0c in 16x2LCD JHD162A to force the cursor to 2nd line. I searched it on internet a lot but cant find it. I am using 89c51 controller and programming it on keil software in Assembly language. LCD module is JHD164A.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's 10dddddddd where dddddddd are the address bits (RW is low)

So to set cursor to start of line 2 it's probably something like 1000100000 (first two bits are RS and R/W)

Here is the [KS0066](http://www.hantronix.com/down/ks0066u.pdf) controller datasheet (I believe that LCD uses) so you can check yourself.

EDIT - most 4 line LCD displays use two controller ICs IIRC, and the addressing is usually:

Line 1 = 0x00
Line 2 = 0x40
Line 3 = 0x10
Line 4 = 0x50

Comment: Thank you very much i googled it out. :-) my 16x4 lcd is now working perfectly.

Comment: @MQA_alex consider accepting the answer then.

Comment: I think the Hitachi interface (i.e. the usual LCD controller) acts like you have a 40 character line width regardless of your actual line width.

Comment: @vicatcu - yes I think you are right, I edited the rest of the addresses in.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much i googled it out. :-)
My 16x4 lcd is now working perfectly. Addresses for the first line are from 0x00 through 0x0f; for second line: 0x40 through 0x4f ; for 3rd line: 0x10 through 0x1f and for 4th line the addresses are: 0x50 through 0x5f....... thus the commands for 1st line will be 0x80+Address; for 2nd it is 0xc0+Address; for 3rd it is 0x90+Address and for 4th line the command will be 0xD0+address. :-) thats the way to programm simple 16x4 LCD....

Best Regards; 
MQA_Alex

Comment: FYI, a 16x4 or 20x4 display is wired electrically like a 32x2 or 40x2 display.  The glass has two independent 80x16 or 100x16 matrices of dots stacked one above the other; corresponding rows on the two matrices are connected together, while the columns are independently connected to the driver chips.  The "out of sequence" addressing is a consequence of that.

Comment: Incidentally, many single-line displays are also subdivided into two matrices, but they're placed side-by-side rather than stacked vertically.  Corresponding column wires are wired together, while rows are wired separately.  This is why many single-line displays have the odd "break" in the middle; wiring them that way only requires half as many column wires from the driver chip.